# Are there any plausible arguments for the infinity of right shifted prime numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes, mersenne-numbers

By *"right shifted prime numbers"* I mean prime numbers of the form:

$p_r \equiv$ $ 1 $ $mod $ $6$.

$p_l \equiv$ $5$ $mod$ $6$ on the other side would be a left shifted prime number.

Since all prime numbers $p_n>3$ are either right shifted or left shifted it seems to be a generalization of a huge amount of much more specific conjectures when simply asking if there are infinitely many right shifted prime numbers at all.

So before bothering about any folow up conjectures like "infinity of Twin primes", "infinity of Mersenne primes" and such, I'd like to understand why there should be infinitely many right shifted prime numbers, while some simple thought experiments don't suggest it:

1. Any amount of right shifted prime factors always results in a right shifted composite number.
2. Any even amount of left shifted prime factors always results in a right shifted composite number.
3. While on the other hand only an odd amount of left shifted prime factors results in a left shifted composite number.

| Primorial - intervals | $30<p<210$ | $210<p<2310$ | $2310<p<30030$ | $30030<p<510510$ | $510510<p<9699690$ | $9699690<p<9699690*23$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All prime numbers | 36 | 297 | 2905 | 39083 | 603698 | 11637502 |
| Left shifted prime numbers | 18 | 150 | 1462 | 19560 | 301928 | 5819042 |
| Right shifted prime numbers | 18 | 147 | 1443 | 19523 | 301770 | 5818460 |
| The gap of right shifts | 0 | 3 | 19 | 37 | 158 | 582 |

While at a first glance the ratios of Right-shifted-primes/All-primes might seem to converge to $0.5$, I highly doubt it, I'd rather expect to see an exponential increase of the right shift gap on further primorial intervals, when all the previous right shift gaps begin to really matter.

The exponential grwoth of gaps between the Mersenne-primes also highly suggests that there aren't infinitely many right shifted primes, since all Mersenne-primes are right shifted. This would then suggest that there exists some final right shifted prime number and no other prime number from there on can ever happen to be right shifted.

Comment: Dirichlet proved that $an+b$ , $n$ running over the natural numbers , produces infinite many primes if and only if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, hence there are infinite mnay primes of the form $6k+1$ and also of the form $6k+5$. On the long run, the ratio of both kinds is $\frac{1}{2}$, although non-residues are usually preferred (Chebychev-bias)

Comment: What exactly is the definition of a right shifted prime? I mean, do you only consider $\mathrm{mod } 6$, or are silly things like $\mathrm{mod } 2$ also allowed?

Comment: That the ratio is $\frac{1}{2}$ is also proven , not just conjectured.

Comment: You can't use 6 and 1 as a and b coprimes, since the fraction of 6/1 can be shorten to 6/1 = 6 which is a contradiction to the definition of two coprimes.

Comment: Eugen-- Note that $\gcd(6,1)=1,$ i.e. $6$ and $1$ are coprime. This has *nothing* to do with the fraction $6/1.$ Look up coprime via google or otherwise.

Comment: Wikipedia: "The numerator and denominator of a reduced fraction are coprime.", what would be the reduced fraction form of 6 and 1?  It's just 6, since 6 and one are not coprime.

Comment: @Eugen Coprime means that their greatest common divisor is $1$. If $6$ and $1$ are not coprime, can you tell me a larger (integral) divisor of $6$ and $1$?

Comment: Also, please clarify exactly what a right shifted prime is, see my first comment.

Comment: @Marktmeister the opening paragraph of the question gives the definition. It's specific to$\bmod 6$.

Comment: @Joffan Yes it does, but it only considers numbers modulo 6. My question was if other moduli are allowed, too. I found it weird because there is the terminology makes it seem that it is not special to the number 6.

Comment: So you'd suggest 1 being coprime to 1 itself, while the new 1 being coprime to 1 and so on? This would btw. imply: a = 1, b = 1, 1*k+1, you're just kidding right? :)

Comment: @Marktmeister I don't see any requirement for further moduli on this, the only usefulness of highermoduli that I could think of here, would be to generate more data for very large primorials,

Comment: @Eugen It's unclear what you mean by your second to last comment. I gave you the definition of coprime integers, which is the usual one. You seem to be arguing that  $6$ and $1$ are not coprime, because $6/1$ is not a reduced fraction. My questions here are: (1) Why only consider $6/1$ but not $1/6$? Since $1/6$ is reduced, shouldn't that mean that $1$ and $6$ are coprime? (2) Why should the fraction $6/1$ not be reduced?

Comment: @Marktmeister The a*n + b argument from Dirichlet is a tautology if you allow that 1 is a coprime to every natural number, so I don't understand what contribution it shall provide on this topic.

Comment: @Eugen It's useless to respond if you keep dodging clarifying questions and immediately jump to different things which are based on your wrong thinking. The wrong thinking I have been trying to point out in my previous comments. I'm out.

Answer (score 3):

*Why there should be infinitely many right shifted prime numbers?*

Suppose there were only finitely many and consider the number $X$ which is the product of all these primes together with $6$.

Let $p$ be a prime which divides $X^2+X+1$. Then $p$ would have to be of the form $6k+5$ since all other primes divide $X$.

By Fermat's little Theorem, $X^{6k+4}=X^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$.

Since $X^3-1=(X^2+X+1)(X-1)$ we also have $X^3\equiv 1\pmod p$.

Therefore $X=X^{(6k+4)-3(2k+1)}\equiv 1\pmod p$.

But then  $X^2+X+1\equiv 3\pmod p$ and is **not** divisible by $p$ after all.

This contradiction proves that there are infinitely many right shifted primes.

Comment: k = 0, You can't use Fermat therefore.

Comment: Ok in that case it would simply imply that p = X^3 -1 itself is an left shifted prime.

Comment: That is absolutely correct and I'm not arguing about that statement, I'm rather missing the point at which it would still contradict my second comment here. Since X^3 - 1 is a left shifted prime itself, there cannot exist an p which divides it and as such it doesn't need to divide x-1 anymore, since it doesn't exists.

Comment: Ok, I see, so it is for every even number n>2, that n^3-1 never can be prime? I don't know this theorem, trying to understand it for now first.

Comment: I don't understand how you try to conclude from X^(6k+4) ≡ 1 mod (6k + 5) that also X ≡ 1 mod (6k+5), how is it possible to conclude this congruency for X from this, if X^(6k+4) ≡ 1 mod (6k+5) then X^(6k+5) ≡ X mod (6k+5), but in no possible way is X ≡ 1 mod (6k+5) from this congruency relation.

Comment: This is fully explained in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\pi(r,m;x)$ denote the count of primes $p$ less than $x$ such that $p\equiv r\,\,\mathrm{mod}\,\,{m}$. It is clear that if $r$ and $m$ are not relatively prime, i.e $\gcd(r,m)>1$, then there can't be infinitely many primes in $\pi(r,m;x)$ since any number $p\equiv r\,\, \mathrm{mod}\,\,m$ factors as $p=r+mk=\gcd(r,m)(r/\gcd(r,m)+m/\gcd(r,m)k)$.

Let $\varphi(m)$ be the count of relatively prime integers less than $m$. A natural generalization of your question is to assume whether or not the primes are in a sense equally distributed across the $\varphi(m)$ possibilities, meaning that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(r,m;x)}{\pi(x)}=\frac{1}{\varphi(m)}$$

Where $\pi(x)$ is the total number of primes less than $x$ (i.e the percentage of primes less than $x$ is $\frac{1}{\varphi(m)}$). Your question is the case $m=6$, where we note that $\varphi(6)=2$ since $1$ and $5$ are the only numbers less than $6$ that are relatively prime to $6$.

This turns out to be very difficult to prove, but it was shown to be true in 1837 and it now known as Dirichlet's Theorem for Primes in Arithmetic Progressions. Research in this direction continues however, since people have notices than the quantities $\frac{\pi(r,m;x)}{\pi(x)}-\frac{1}{\varphi(m)}$ seem to have "preferences" for being positive or negative, meaning that for a given value of $r$ we generally see slightly less primes than expected.

This phenomenon is very interesting, and I highly recommend you check it out and learn more if you are interested.